# Join 2 evaluate Queries in DAX

Tags: ssas, olap-cube, ssas-2008, ssas-2012, ssas-tabular

Friends

Today I would like to join the result of 2 evaluate Query in DAX Query can any one have the way to do it? Following are the codes of 2 evaluate queries which i would like to join.

```
 evaluate
(
filter
    (
   summarize
   (
     'Total Days',
     'Total Days'[Month],
     'Total Days'[Number]
      ),  AND('Total Days'[Month]>=201601 , 'Total Days'[Month]<201612)
   )   
)

EVALUATE
filter
    (

    SUMMARIZE (
        'Sales Data',
        'Date'[DateSID],
        'Date'[Month],
        'Office'[Number]    
    )
,  AND('Date'[Month]>=201601 , 'Date'[Month]<201612)
)
```

I want to perform an inner join based on(Month, Number) in above 2 DAX queries.
I need following table as an output.

```
'Total Days'[Month]     'Total Days'[Number]     'Date'[DateSID]
```

Comment: yes I have 2016 and already try this but function not works with for above 2 queries

Comment: I want to perform join here not "UNION"